# Fetch value using 'case' in scala

Tags: scala

I am new in scala, don't be mad at me for a nub question, please help me see how `case` parsing works on my example:

I want to parse such string:

```
6546263252026003359  192.168.1.1
```

So basically I want split them by  and parse the first one as `Integer` and the second one `IPAdress` to a such structure:

```
class IPAddress(val cartage1 : Integer, cartage2 : Integer, cartage3: Integer, cartage4 : Integer) {

}
```

Could you please help me to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose by "case parsing" you mean the [extractor](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) of the [regex class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/util/matching/Regex.html)? Well, a simple variant would be the following:

```
scala> val pattern = """(\d+)\s+(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})""".r
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\d+)\s+(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})

scala> val pattern(d, i1, i2, i3, i4) = "6546263252026003359  192.168.1.1"
d: String = 6546263252026003359
i1: String = 192
i2: String = 168
i3: String = 1
i4: String = 1
```

Whereby the regex should probably be worked on, if you want to ensure valid IPs.

What happens underneath is that `pattern` defines an `unapply` method of type `String => Option[(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)]`, so that something like

```
"6546263252026003359  192.168.1.1" match {
  case pattern(d, i1, i2, i3, i4) => IPAddress(i1, i2, i3, i4)
}
```

gets (roughtly) translated to this:

```
pattern.unapply("6546263252026003359  192.168.1.1") match {
  case Some((d, i1, i2, i3, i4)) => IPAddress(i1, i2, i3, i4)
  case None => /* throw some error */
}
```

The pattern assignment shown above works similar, it just modifies the local environment. Technicalities can be looked up [here](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~emir/written/MatchingObjectsWithPatterns-TR.pdf) and probably in the [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain what is execution of  `val pattern(d, i1, i2, i3, i4) = "6546263252026003359  192.168.1.1"` technically

Comment: I've added further explanation.